# Send a websocket message when exceptions is raised in django channels

Tags: python, django, channel

I'm using django-channels. When an exception is raised within a consumer it will log the error, the websocket connection will be disconnected and then it will re-connect again.

I would like to send a websocket message before it disconnects. I've tried to catch the error, send the message and then re-raise the exception. But the message still isn't sent.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: You can get a error message from websocket before it disconnects by using `onerror` event listener.

Comment: @AjayLingayat, on a server error no error event is sent out to the frontend. I tried adding an event listener for onerror on the frontend and nothing shows. I can see the open event and the close event though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you raise an error it seems like the the actual raising of the error takes precedence of sending the message which happens later.

So the solution I went with in the end was to catch the exception in place, append the exception and check whether there were any exceptions to be raised after a message was sent.

If there was an error to raise, raise it. That way errors are raised server side and any errors will get known frontend side as well.

Alternatively, which might be a better solution. Catch the error and then log the exception. Have a special method that sends the error back to frontend and then return early.

That way the server will never disconnect and there is no need for re-connection. Which saves some time and processing.